# `org-html-export-to-html` not adding color for the code blocks

Tags: org-mode, org-export, html

I have an org file with the following code block:

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
(+ 1 2)
#+end_src
```

And when I export it using `M-x org-html-export-to-html`, the code blocks in the generated file have no color.

They have a `src` and a `src-emacs-lisp` CSS classes, but the only thing inside the file is:

```css
pre.src-emacs-lisp:before { content: 'Emacs Lisp'; }
```

I have `org-src-fontify-natively` set to `t`, and I tried using both `css` and `inline-css` as values for `org-html-htmlize-output-type`, but nothing fixed it.

I remember exporting as HTML some months ago in a different machine, and the code blocks had color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install `htmlize` package with `M-x package-install RET htmlize RET`.

Org export uses `htmlize` to highlight code blocks in html.